# How to call Gensim's LsiModel save?

Tags: gensim

On https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/lsimodel.html#gensim.models.lsimodel.LsiModel.save, function `save` has the prototype:

```
save(fname, *args, **kwargs)
```

I'd like to understand what `args` and `kwargs` are, and how to pass them to `save`. However, the document doesn't explain these.

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find out what these arguments are?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the `args` and `kwargs` parameters and just provide the filename.

Their [gensim tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/lsimodel.html) pages have sample code, e.g.

```
model = LsiModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary)
model.save("lsi.model")
```